# How to capitalize if an alphanumeric is in a word/sentence

Tags: python

I am not able to use .title() for a alphanumeric word/sentence. It throws any syntax error

```
def LetterCapitalize(str): 
    x=str.title()
    return x

print LetterCapitalize(raw_input())


def LetterCapitalize(str): 
    x=str.title()
    return x

print LetterCapitalize(raw_input())


def LetterCapitalize(str): 
    x=str.title()
    return x

# keep this function call here  
print LetterCapitalize(raw_input())

File "/tmp/329948743/main.py", line 6    
print LetterCapitalize(m3k mml)
                             ^SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

**note**: *m3k mml* is the string I have passed

Comment: `mk3 mml` is two undefined variables, `"mk3 mml"` is a string.

Comment: First of all, you shouldn't use `str` as variable name because it is an built-in keyword, on the other hand your function argument has to be `string` type because only string object has `title` method.

Comment: I was on the code contest and there we need to use the above format

Answer (score 0):

The syntax in the function call is incorrect

```
print LetterCapitalize(m3k mml)
```

Those are 2 variables m3k and mml, to print them you can either:

```
print LetterCapitalize(m3k + mml)
```

to print both variables concatenated or:

```
print LetterCapitalize("m3k mml")
```

if you want to print the string *M3k Mml*

Comment: but when I tried 'hello world' thee answer came 'Hello World'

Comment: why with this does it have a problem

Comment: Because you used quotes with 'hello world'

Comment: I didn't there in the contest

Comment: how did you call the function: `print LetterCapitalize('hello world')` or `print LetterCapitalize(hello world)`